# How to inform the colleagues that they didn't cite sources in their internal knowledge sharing?

Tags: ethics, references

In an internal knowledge sharing by a team from a different subsidiary, I found that I cannot understand a key point, and in the Q&A session I asked a question about that and the presenter answered it but I still cannot comprehend that totally. After the Q&A session, I messaged the presenter asking if he could refer some materials on that topic to me and he sent me two links to two papers(one published in 2021 and the other in 2020, very new). I thought that technique was invented by themselves since there were no references in their slides, but it turned out that they were not involved in the two studies.

The head of the team has a doctorate degree from a prestigious university in the world and she should know that they [should](https://poorvucenter.yale.edu/writing/using-sources/understanding-and-avoiding-plagiarism/warning-when-you-must-cite) put the citations in their slides. And it reminds me of another sharing where a different team from the same subsidiary also didn't add any references.

Is it normal in internal knowledge sharing? It was coordinated by our boss, and it's not a very formal presentation. How can I politely inform them of the issue? Is it necessary?

Comment: @PlayerOne So, it's not necessary to cite the sources. Thank you.

Comment: In a formal thesis one must cite everything to show it's not self invented and show the person has understood how to work scientifically. In contrast to that I think in a simple transfer of knowledge accompanied by slides, people are hardly interested in where something comes from. Here a link is nice to go deeper into details but probably is not formally expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty typical in the corporate world.  It is not something to worry overmuch about.

Depending on the topic, it may be something that is considered very common knowledge in their field.

You asked, he sent you the papers, you now have more information, and more citations to continue research on the topic.

Comment: No, it's not common knowledge. They are both very recent studies, published in 2020 and 2021.

Comment: Doesn't matter. They're not trying to publish research journals, but are simply doing presentation on ideas. The premise is not academic research or studies, but knowledge. If it is truly malicious, they would've given you fake papers with their name on it instead of the original with the real authors. The presentation is not in academic context, so don't impose academic rigors and requirements onto them.